# requestAnimationFrame with callback function?

Tags: javascript

Upon clicking a button, I'm animating some things on the canvas. Once the animations are done, I want to invoke a function which is passed as a parameter into the function which initialized `requestAnimationFrame` in the first place.

Is this possible?

I tried various approaches, with anonymous functions etc.

```
var anim = false;
var game = new Game();

function Game(){
  this.turn = 1;

  this.move = function(){
    this.animate(game.advanceTurn);
  }

  this.advanceTurn = function(){
     this.turn++;
  }

  this.animate = function(callback){
    var done = false;
    anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(game.animate);

    // animation code here

    if (done){
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
        anim = false;
        callback();
    }
  }
```

i.e. click button, animate stuff, animation is done, call game.advanceTurn.

When logging the arguments supplied, the console will at first log my callback function but then replace it with what I believe is a timer measurement (fits with MDN description of `rAF` description).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `bind` to let your callback function be passed on. At the same time you can also pass on `this`, so you keep your reference to the current Game object instance:

```js
function Game(){
  var i = 0;
  var anim = false;
  
  this.turn = 1;

  this.move = function(){
    this.animate(this.advanceTurn.bind(this));
  }

  this.advanceTurn = function(){
     this.turn++;
  }

  this.animate = function(callback){
    var done = false;
    anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this, callback));

    // animation code here
    console.log(i++);

    if (i>5){
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
        i = 0;
        anim = false;
        callback();
    }
  }
}

new Game().animate(function () {
   console.log('callback received');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**You are not writing your class properly.**

In your `Game` class you are using the variable `game`, but you should be using `this`.

For instance,

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(game.animate);
```

should be

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
```

And why are you setting `anim` to `false`? `requestAnimationFrame` [returns a non-zero number of type `long.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

`this.turn` should start at 0, not one.

It doesn't make sense for `move` to call `animate`.

In fact, the structure you are trying to use is digging you a grave.

I think it would be best for you to just re-start, and do it right the second time.

[Try this tutorial :)](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/)